# How to set value to EnvironmentObject from class?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to set value to EnvironmentObject from Delegate class.

```
struct AppleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewViewModel: MapViewViewModel
  let mapViewDelegate = MapViewDelegate()
  class MapViewDelegate: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didChange mode: MKUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool) {
     // This is where I want to set value to EnvObj
     **mapViewViewModel.mode = mode**
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I want to do.

My code gives error

```
Instance member 'mapViewViewModel' of type 'AppleMapView' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'AppleMapView.MapViewDelegate'
```

So, I've tried giving reference to delegate class:

`MapViewDelegate(vm: mapViewViewModel)`
This has no compile error, but when I run the code it made errors

````
A View.environmentObject(_:) for MapViewViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.4.3/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55 ```
````

Neither works. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in different way, it needs to make your `MapViewDelegate` as coordinator for `AppleMapView`, like below

```
struct AppleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewViewModel: MapViewViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator // << your delegate
        return mapView
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewDelegate {
        MapViewDelegate(self)   // << will be created for you
    }

  class MapViewDelegate: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var owner: AppleMapView
    init(_ owner: AppleMapView) {
      self.owner = owner
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didChange mode: MKUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool) {
       owner.mapViewViewModel.mode = mode // << now you have access to owner props
    }
  }
}
```